# getting postion of a control in mousemove

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight control in which i am dynamically creating shapes on button click
These shapes are draggable across the form. Now i want to get top and left postion of a control on dragging (mousemove). Please help

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your question history I can think of two approaches.  I suspect that the shape is simply being placed on a `Canvas` and the `MouseMove` of which you speak refers to an event handler you've attached to the `Canvas`.  On that basis then.

```
void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 

    Type currentType = e.OriginalSource.GetType();

    // Make decisions based on value of currentType here 

    DependencyObject source = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
    Point p = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(source), Canvas.GetTop(source));

}
```

The more general solution is to use the `TransformToVisual` approach.  Something like:-

```
var transform = ((UIElement)e.OriginalSource).TransformToVisual(MyCanvas);
Point p = transform.Transform(Point(0,0));
```